# creating a variable inside a struct leads to an error due to the constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, struct

I was writing the following code and any variable that I created dragged an error:

```
struct ParagraphInfo
    {
        public ParagraphInfo(string text)
        { 

        }

        int i;
    }
```

The error is:

> Field 'ConsoleApplication15.Program.ParagraphInfo.i'

must be fully assigned before control is returned to the caller

The constructor was underlined as the source of the error and once I deleted it the error disappeared.

What is going on?

Comment: Did you try adding `: this()` after your constructor signature definition?

Answer (score 1):

When the compiler generates a constructor for your `struct`, everything within the struct is initialized:

```
struct ParagraphInfo {
    int i;
}

ParagraphInfo pi = new ParagraphInfo();
// pi.i == 0 here.
```

This is a guarantee that you need to ensure as well if you create your own constructor. This will compile:

```
struct ParagraphInfo {
    int i;
    public ParagraphInfo(string text) {
        i = 0; // you've guaranteed i is initialized.
    }
}
```

Or..

```
struct ParagraphInfo {
    int i;
    public ParagraphInfo(string text) : this() {

    }
}
```

You can use `this()` because the default constructor does the initializing for you.

Comment: The default constructor (parameterless constructor) set all the struct members to their default values. This is why @SimonWhitehead uses _this()_ in the second version of the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of the `Struct` types all field values must be assigned. So initialize `i` in your constructor or change the `ParagraphInfo` to `class`.

```
public ParagraphInfo(string text)
{     
    this.i = 0;
}

int i;
```